# Responsive polygon (triangle) SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive

I'm trying to build a page with 2 polygons, but i'm facing some problems with aspect ratio on mobile or tablet mode.

Check the codepen and resize the window, you will see that the red triangle doesn't keep correct shape as well as the icon inside.

Would be really nice if you can help me to accomplish this.

Best regards and thanks a lot

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden;
} 
.wrap-layer {
 position:absolute;
 top:0; 
 height:100%; 
 width:100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}
.content {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:1;
 top: 50%;  
 right:55%;
 color: #fff;
}
svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}
#play {
 content: "\e907";
 font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
 fill: #fff;
 font-size:5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrap-layer">
 
  <div class="content">
   <h1>Bla bla</h1>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   
   <polygon id="blue" points="80 0, 50 100, 0 100, 0 0" fill="#000" />
     
   <!-- HOW TO KEEP SHAPE OF THE RED TRIANGLE IN RESPONSIVE -->
   <!-- HOW ADD font icon and KEEP THE SHAPE -->
      <g>
    <polygon id="trigger-play" points="50 100, 56 80, 62 100" fill="red" />
     <text id="play" x=53 y=95>&#xe907;</text>
   </g>   
  </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/lulu2312/pen/oVQegd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute to:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice"
```

The `xMid` part means centre in the X direction. `YMax` means bottom align in the Y direction. The purpose of that is to ensure the red triangle will be visible.  The `slice` means grow the SVG so that it completely fills the parent, overflowing if necessary.  Basically the same as CSS's `background-size: cover`.

You can learn more about how `preserveAspectRatio` works in the SVG specification.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#coords-PreserveAspectRatioAttribute

If the current angles and shapes are not what you want, then you will need to redesign the SVG so it has a different aspect ratio.  At the moment it is 1:1 (square).

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden;
} 
.wrap-layer {
 position:absolute;
 top:0; 
 height:100%; 
 width:100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}
.content {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:1;
 top: 50%;  
 right:55%;
 color: #fff;
}
svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}
#play {
 content: "\e907";
 font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
 fill: #fff;
 font-size:5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrap-layer">
 
  <div class="content">
   <h1>Bla bla</h1>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
   
   <polygon id="blue" points="80 0, 50 100, 0 100, 0 0" fill="#000" />
     
   <!-- HOW TO KEEP SHAPE OF THE RED TRIANGLE IN RESPONSIVE -->
   <!-- HOW ADD font icon and KEEP THE SHAPE -->
      <g>
    <polygon id="trigger-play" points="50 100, 56 80, 62 100" fill="red" />
     <text id="play" x=53 y=95>&#xe907;</text>
   </g>   
  </svg>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/BbGwKp

Comment: Awesone, thank you really much for your answer, exactely what i need